# Performance: assign boolean value always or check value first?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, boolean

I'm sure it is negligible, but given that I want to assign `true` to a boolean field from within a method, does this choice make any difference? If so, why?

```
field = true; // could already be true, but I don't care
```

versus

```
if(!field) field = true;
```

Comment: I agree with you, I'm sure it's negligible! Seriously though a much more interesting question is which one is more clear and so easier to maintain.

Comment: and as for your actual question the two different paths in the version with the if will take different times so you can't really answer without knowing the probability of each path occurring. That said I'd find it hard to believe the plain unconditional assignment would be beaten.

Comment: If I have such a problem I'll using first one who care about performance in this case, it's your convention.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd say no. But this does depend on the fact that we really are talking about a *field* as opposed to a *property*, which **may** (though it definitely should not) exhibit different behavior in the two snippets you included (i.e., if there is logic with side effects in the getter).

**Update**: If you're talking about performance overhead, there is practically no difference—**but** I believe assignment is ever-so-slightly less expensive (than reading the value). Here is a sample program to demonstrate this:

```
bool b = false;

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; ++i)
{
    b = true;
}
sw.Stop();

TimeSpan setNoCheckTime = sw.Elapsed;

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; ++i)
{
    // This part will never assign, as b will always be true.
    if (!b)
    {
        b = true;
    }
}
sw.Stop();

TimeSpan checkSetTime = sw.Elapsed;

Console.WriteLine("Assignment: {0} ms", setNoCheckTime.TotalMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine("Read: {0} ms", checkSetTime.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Output on my machine:

```
Assignment: 2749.6285 ms
Read: 4543.0343 ms
```

Comment: Right, I'm only asking about fields -- does assignment or value-checking have greater overhead? Properties are another story altogether. Setters could easily have overhead, as well, such as comparing `value` against a field, raising property change notifications, etc.

Comment: @Jay: OK, I thought by "difference" you meant different *behavior*. If we're talking about overhead, assignment seems (from my own test) to have *slightly* less overhead. I will add an example program.

Comment: @Jay You aren't comparing assignment and value-checking: you are comparing assignment and value-checking followed, possibly, by assignment.

Comment: I honestly doubt memory writes are faster/slower than reads. Do note that your second case (which does no writes) does a compare and a branch, compared to the first test which only does a single write.

Comment: @David: You're right, but if what Jay *really* wants to compare is assignment versus value checking, that is what the example program above effectively does.

Comment: Forgive me for seeming obtuse, but if memory serves, the compiler converts public fields to properties. In that case, there'd be no timing difference between a public field and a public property (assuming there's no code in the setter). For private fields, the compiler may do the same. TL;DR version: I don't see any performance increase from using fields over properties.

Comment: @Jakob: Good point (I'm too ignorant of lower-level stuff to have thought of that). Come to think of it, can you even think of a way (in C#) to time the performance of *just* a read? A field by itself is not a legal statement; but if you assign it to a local variable then suddenly you've got an assignment.

Comment: @Dan Then we'd be into mind-reading! ;-) I must say I am astonished by the volume of questions like this on SO that focus on performance of things that will clearly have no impact on performance. The factors that drive performance appear to be misunderstood astoundingly frequently.

Comment: @David: That may be; but I wouldn't be too quick to assume that just because someone's asking a certain type of question, he/she must be misinformed about performance issues in general. Everyone's allowed to just be curious, right?

Comment: @Mike: I've never heard of the compiler converting fields to properties automatically. It may *inline* properties with no custom logic in their getters/setters, effectively making them perform the same as fields; but that's the opposite. Also, unless I'm mistaken this only happens with sealed types. *Also*, I think the point that Marc and I made deals with the scenario where there *is* custom logic in a property getter and/or setter—this *will* affect performance and *may* affect behavior as well.

Answer (score 11):

For a field, just set it. For a property, it could be more complex, depending on whether the `get` or `set` is disproportionately expensive, and/or whether the `set` checks this internally (bypassing events etc).

As a general rule for properties, just set it, until you know this to be an issue due to profiling.

For fields; don't worry excessively about it; default to just set.

Comment: Of course, a property that takes a significant amount of time to `set` (and doesn't check if that would be redundant) is either a WTF or something very rare with very very good reasoning.

Answer (score 7):

Back in the 90s when I did program in x86 assembler, the rule was (IIRC) to avoid jumps. An `if` statement would have been implemented as a jump.

So my conclusion would be (under the assumtion that at least *some* of those ancient rules still apply) that avoiding the `if` and assigning directly would be more performant.

Comment: This is the answer I was searching for. Thanks for that Uwe ✌

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is if I am expecting something other then the default value for any type of variable I set it to something it normally wouldn't be.  This way if the value didn't change, then I know what to expect and how to handle it. It wouldn't really be appliciable to your examples, your question is sort of vague, your examples don't explain what your attempting to do.

I agree with Marc's and Dan's statements of course.