# Conditional assigning a value to int variable in loop (optimization)

Tags: optimization, variable-assignment

Let's say that we have two dimensional array of **bool**s which represent map of simple game. Every cell of array can be set to **true** if cell is occupied by some game's object (else **false**).

We want to update map in loop regarding to objects' behaviour. Let's say (because of some reasons) we are not able to update only some regions of the map, we have to iterate every cell in the array and negate it's value if object has changed its position.

We know that in every array's update there are only few changes but array is huge. And now comes the question.
What is more optimal.

(1) This:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
    {
        bool newValue = update(i,j);
        arr[i,j] = arr[i,j] != newValue ? newValue : arr[i,j];
    }
```

(2) this:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
    {
        bool newValue = update(i,j);
        if(newValue != arr[i,j])
            arr[i,j] = newValue;
    }
```

(3) or maybe this:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
    {
        arr[i,j] = update(i,j);
    }
```

I think (1) is worst solution here. So (2) vs (3).

Comment: I think the differences between 2 and 3 will be so small that the difference will not be important, so go with what is the simplest (3). That seems to agree with this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586795/performance-assign-boolean-value-always-or-check-value-first

Answer (score 0):

No 3. There is no reason to write the code like you did in #2. You can remove the if without any problems.