# Which is more expensive - assigning a value always or checking for null and then assigning

Tags: c#, performance

Consider the below C# example. Which would be more efficient?
I am curious to know if repetitive 'if' condition check will be costlier than just assigning the value directly.

In my code I have situation - there is a block of code that gets executed every time user request is received. I want to set a particular global key value that I want to use for subsequent logging (null gets logged till there is a value). The problem is the value for the key can be received in any request which cannot be determined, once I set it I don't need to set the value any more.

The while loop below is just to simulate the repetitive code execution for all user requests. The 'value' property will be set in some request.

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var value = null; // some data received from user that later set the value
var i = 0;
while (i < 1000)
{
   if(data["key"] == null)
   {
      data["key"] = value;
   }

}

vs

while (i < 1000)
{
   data["key"] = value;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4586795/1693085 and the one answer, maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4587052/1693085

Comment: Try both and measure.  Then you'll know.

Comment: You have to measure it to be sure about it. [If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I believe this is a perfect case to say *premature optimization is the evil of any project!*

Comment: The two code examples are not semantically the same. So it's irrelevant which one is faster, because you're going to use the one that actually meets the requirements for _correctness_, rather than picking one based on performance.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer will be 'It depends'. The compiler applies too many optimizations to your code. So it's hard enough to predict how the generated IL code look like.
But in general on operation is faster than two. Especially in case of using dictionary which executes hash-computation logic to find value by key.

Answer (score 0):

In this example the 'if' is negligible performance vs dictionary lookup. So Case 2 should be much quicker because you do a dictionary lookup only once.